# Java - Parallelizing Gzip

Tags: java, gzip, parallel-processing

I was assigned to parallelize GZip in Java 7, and I am not sure which is possible.

The assignment is:

- Parallelize gzip using a given number of threads
- Each thread takes a 1024 KiB block, using the last 32 KiB block from
  the previous block as a dictionary. There is an option to use no
  dicitionary
- Read from Stdin and stdout

What I have tried:

- I have tried using GZIPOutputStream, but there doesn't seem to be a
  way to isolate and parallelize the deflate(), nor can I access the
  deflater to alter the dictionary. I tried extending off of GZIPOutputStream, but it didn't seem to act as I wanted to, since I still couldn't isolate the compress/deflate.
- I tried using Deflater with wrap enabled and a FilterOutputStream to
  output the compressed bytes, but I wasn't able to get it to compress
  properly in GZip format. I made it so each thread had a compressor that will write to a byte array, then it will write to the OutputStream.

I am not sure if I am did my approaches wrong or took the wrong approaches completely. Can anyone point me the right direction for which classes to use for this project?

Comment: Is this homework? It certainly seems like the intent is for you to implement this from scratch, rather than copy `GZIPOutputStream` if so. As you say that class is not parallelized already for you.

Comment: The GzipOutputStream is a wrapper round the Deflater, surely?

Comment: Yea, this is a homework assignment. I was told Deflaters should work, but I can't seem to get them to compress properly in GZip format.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, zipping a file with dictionary can't be parallelized, as everything depends on everything. Maybe your teacher asked you to parallelize the individual gzipping of multiple files in a folder? That would be a great example of parallelized work.

Comment: We are supposed to read the blocks in sequentially, set the dictionaries of each block using the last 32 KiB from the previously read block, then compress concurrently.

Comment: As far as I know parallelized compression is a big deal, and it's not something used a lot. I'm pretty sure gzip doesn't allow for parallelization, but there are however other compression formats that allo for it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2 (not that this implementation has never made it to the main project, so I wouldn't put my money on it)

Answer (score 2):

I ***think*** you can do it by inserting appropriate resets in the compression stream. The idea is that the underlying compression engine used in gzip *allows* the [deflater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) to be reset, with an aim that it makes it easier to recover from stream corruption, though at a cost of making the compression ratio worse. After reset, the deflater will be in a known state and thus you could in fact start from that state (which is independent of the content being compressed) in multiple threads (and from many locations in the input data, of course) produce a compressed chunk and include the data produced when doing the following reset so that it takes the deflater back to the known state. Then you've just to reassemble the compressed pieces into the overall compressed stream. “Simple!” (Hah!)

I don't know if this will work, and I suspect that the complexity of the whole thing will make it not a viable choice except when you're compressing single very large files. (If you had many files, it would be *much* easier to just compress each of those in parallel.) Still, that's what I'd try first.

(Also note that the gzip format is just a deflated stream with extra metadata.)

Comment: I'm also not sure that you can do it with the Java interface to the zlib engine. It's possible that it doesn't expose _quite_ enough. It doesn't help that the documentation of what to do to create recoverable streams is also somewhat sketchy…

Answer (score 1):

To make a process concurrent, you need to have portions of code which can run concurrently and independently.  Most compression algorithms are designed to be run sequentially, where every byte depends on every byte has comes before.

The only way to do compression concurrently is to change the algorythm (making it incompatible with existing approaches)